# change colors of triangles of a plane threeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to build a multicolor plane changing the colors of the triangles of the mesh.
is it possible to modify the colors of triangles from the mesh of a PlaneGeometry object?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/15cdo8ag/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible as I wanted because overtime you have a mesh and you setup the colors by vertex the result is an interpolation. And you will obtain an beautiful degrade. The best way to resolve this problem is to make different meshes and configurate their materials by separated.